# while writing Junit test cases for @post method, i am getting null pointer exception at userService.addUser() mehod. could anyone help here

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, microservices

```
public class UserService {
        
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        
        @Autowired
        private ConverterService converterService;
        public User addUser(UserDto userdto) {
            User convertedUser = converterService.convertToEntity(userdto);
            convertedUser.setUserId(userdto.getUserId());
            convertedUser.setUserName(userdto.getUserName());
            User savedUser = userRepository.save(convertedUser); 
            return savedUser;
        }
    }
```

//while debugging userRepository.save(convertedUser) method, it always returning null.

Below is my UserServiceTest.java class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class UserServiceTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
    
        @Mock
        private ConverterService converterService;
    
        @MockBean
        private UserRepository userRepository;
    
        @Test
        public void addUserTest() {
            UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
            userDto.setUserId("123");
            userDto.setUserName("AB");
            User user = new User("123","ABC");
            Mockito.when(converterService.convertToEntity(new UserDto())).thenReturn(user);
            Mockito.when(userRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(user);
            User user1 = userService.addUser(userDto);
            Assert.assertEquals(user,userService.addUser(userDto));
    
        }
    }
```

userService.addUser(userDto) this method is always return by null from service class. because of below condition is failing : Assert.assertEquals(user,userService.addUser(userDto));

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't pass null value to the assertEquals method. But you can do like this;

```
Assert.assertEquals(Objects.equals(user,userService.addUser(userDto)),true);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. i did but getting below error.

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :false
Actual   :true

Comment: this is expected case, you must focus on why user and userService.addUser(userDto) are not equal. Why your repository returns null?,   also make sure that  equals method  is used properly inside User class.

Comment: Thankyou sgorgulu, now its working, problem is i haven't override equal and hashcode() method inside entity class.